# Spring projections select collection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I am attempting to have a station projection include a list of associated logos. Below is my domain:

```
@Table(name = "Station")
public class Station implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
private int id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "station")
private Set<Logo> logos;
}
```

The @OneToMany associated logos:

```
@Table(name = "Logo")
public class Logo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Transient
private String fullUrl; // calculated

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "StationId", nullable = false)
private Station station;
}
```

My repository and query is as follows:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.id AS Id, s.logos As Logos FROM Station s JOIN s.users su WHERE su.username = ?1")
Collection<StationListViewProjection> findStationsByUsername(String username);
```

My station projection expects the Id and a list of logoProjections

```
@Projection(name = "StationListViewProjection", types = Station.class)
public interface StationListViewProjection {
   int getId();
   Set<LogoProjection> getLogos();
}
```

The logoProjection only needs the url

```
@Projection(name = "LogoProjection", types = Logo.class)
public interface LogoProjection {
   String getFullUrl();
}
```

When i execute my query I get a strange response:

MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_5_0_, . as col_6_0_, stationlog3_.id as id1_20_0_'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this

```
@Transient
private String fullUrl; // calculated
```

correct, your `fullUrl` gets calculated inside your java code and more important, it doesn't have a matching column in the database. You can't use such field in projections directly. You might be able to use an [Open Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open) and specify the calculation to obtain the `fullUrl` using a `@Value` annotation.